# Python Regular Expression For Host Header

Tags: python, regex

Given this string:

```
GET /dsadda HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.26.0\r\nHost: www.youtube.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n
```

How would I obtain everything in a Python regex group between `Host:` and `\r\n`?

In this example, I would like `re.match.group(1)` to return `www.youtube.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this Regex to match

```
>>> a = 'GET /dsadda HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.26.0\r\nHost: www.youtube.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n'
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"Host: (.+)\r\n",a).group(1)
'www.youtube.com'
```

*Small Note* - It is better to use `re.MULTILINE` flag as the input string contains `\n`, though it is not required in this particular case. 
*Additionally*, As [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592048/python-regular-expression-for-host-header/28592079?noredirect=1#comment45576341_28592079) mentions, using the `^` to match the start of the string is also a better option, as there may be Header fields with the name `Host`. Thus the final regex would be something like `re.search(r"^Host: (.+)\r\n",a,re.M).group(1)`.

Comment: This could match something like "X-Original-Host" if it was there, thus, the `re.M` along with `^` could be a good idea

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry for the late reply, had gone to sleep. But is there any field in HTTP header like "Original-Host"? If yes, then `^` will be a necessity!

Answer (score 1):

using positive look behind and positive look ahead

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'GET /dsadda HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.26.0\r\nHost: www.youtube.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n' 
>>> re.search(r"(?<=Host: )(\S+)(?=\r\n)", a).group(1)
'www.youtube.com'
```